# Different price per customer for a product

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find the solution yet.

We need to have different prices per customer for the same product. These prices should be shown on the list of products.

Is there any way to do this?

We are using

```
Joomla 2.5.7
VM 2.0.18a
```

Thank you in advance,

Bhavik Mulia

Comment: Have you tried posting on the VW forums or contacting the developer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tax and Calculation rules for achieving this,

- Create Different shopper group for your shoppers.
- Create tax and calculation rules using margin option.
- Assign it to the shopper group.

You have done. Just check the listing and details page.

Hope its helps..

Comment: This is the only way in VirtueMart to do it without core hacks.

Comment: Is this possible without setting prices per shopper group but per customer?

Comment: no , but you can achieve by a trick like if your registration form is customized or override you can push that users to the correct  group.

Comment: I have no idea what you say please describe in details what actual you say?

Comment: Per customer means you need to set all customers different price ? I think its not like that you have some basic categories like Wholesale,retail etc. So by default any user register in joomla it will consider default shopper group you have to assign that user to the proper shopper group.If your registration form have such a field like wholesaler or retailer option you can push that users directly to that group. make its sense